# Styleguidist: Module not found errors

Tags: react-styleguidist

I am trying to get Styleguidist to run in an existing React environment.

When running

```
yarn styleguidist build
```

I get errors like this:

[image]

My styleguide.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  components: 'src/components/**/[A-Z]*.js',
  webpackConfig: {
    module: {
      rules: [
        // Babel loader, will use your project’s babel.config.js
        {
          test: /\.jsx?$/,
          exclude: /node_modules/,
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          query: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
        // Other loaders that are needed for your components
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: ['style-loader', 'css-loader']
        }    
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

1. How can I help Styleguidist to resolve the imports inside a 
   component?
2. How can I prevent Styleguidist to search inside the
   node_modues folder? I thought          "exclude: /node_modules/"
   does    that already?

Comment: Did you figure out how to solve this?